# usbmuxd for multiple idevices

Tags: iphone, ssh, openssh

By using usbmuxd with the help of following command..

> tcprelay.py -t 5900

I am able to connect to iphone with VNC viewer by giving hostname as 127.0.0.1 and port as 5900.
By using above command i able to connect to the last connected iphone.

Now how can i connect to multiple devices at same time by using usbmuxd.
i studied in documentation of usbmuxd that we can connect to multiple devices.
I seen help but unable to workout on it.
can anyone kindly give suggestions.

Iphone is jail broken with veency, openssh installed

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest version of tcprelay.py (http://cgit.sukimashita.com/usbmuxd.git, v1.0.8), multiple device support is not yet implemented. Commands are always sent to the first device:

```
    print "Waiting for devices..."
    if not mux.devices:
        mux.process(1.0)
    if not mux.devices:
        print "No device found"
        self.request.close()
        return
    dev = mux.devices[0]
```

This has to be changed to something like:

```
    dev = None
    while dev is None:
        for d in mux.devices:
            if d.serial == self.server.serial:
                dev = d
                print "Found the device %s"%str(dev)
                break
        if dev is None:
            mux.process()
```

Here's the complete tcprelay.py, I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#   tcprelay.py - TCP connection relay for usbmuxd
#
# Copyright (C) 2009    Hector Martin "marcan" <hector@marcansoft.com>
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 2 or version 3.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA

import usbmux
import SocketServer
import select
from optparse import OptionParser
import sys
import threading

class SocketRelay(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, maxbuf=65535):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.atob = ""
        self.btoa = ""
        self.maxbuf = maxbuf
    def handle(self):
        while True:
            rlist = []
            wlist = []
            xlist = [self.a, self.b]
            if self.atob:
                wlist.append(self.b)
            if self.btoa:
                wlist.append(self.a)
            if len(self.atob) < self.maxbuf:
                rlist.append(self.a)
            if len(self.btoa) < self.maxbuf:
                rlist.append(self.b)
            rlo, wlo, xlo = select.select(rlist, wlist, xlist)
            if xlo:
                return
            if self.a in wlo:
                n = self.a.send(self.btoa)
                self.btoa = self.btoa[n:]
            if self.b in wlo:
                n = self.b.send(self.atob)
                self.atob = self.atob[n:]
            if self.a in rlo:
                s = self.a.recv(self.maxbuf - len(self.atob))
                if not s:
                    return
                self.atob += s
            if self.b in rlo:
                s = self.b.recv(self.maxbuf - len(self.btoa))
                if not s:
                    return
                self.btoa += s
            #print "Relay iter: %8d atob, %8d btoa, lists: %r %r %r"%(len(self.atob), len(self.btoa), rlo, wlo, xlo)

class TCPRelay(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        print "Incoming connection to %d"%self.server.server_address[1]
        mux = usbmux.USBMux(options.sockpath)

        #print "Waiting for devices..."
        #if not mux.devices:
        #   mux.process(1.0)
        #if not mux.devices:
        #   print "No device found"
        #   self.request.close()
        #   return
        #dev = mux.devices[0]

        dev = None
        while dev is None:
            for d in mux.devices:
                if d.serial == self.server.serial:
                    dev = d
                    print "Found the device %s"%str(dev)
                    break
            if dev is None:
                mux.process()

        print "Connecting to device %s"%str(dev)
        dsock = mux.connect(dev, self.server.rport)
        lsock = self.request
        print "Connection established, relaying data"
        try:
            fwd = SocketRelay(dsock, lsock, self.server.bufsize * 1024)
            fwd.handle()
        finally:
            dsock.close()
            lsock.close()
        print "Connection closed"

class TCPServer(SocketServer.TCPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True

class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, TCPServer):
    pass

HOST = "localhost"

parser = OptionParser(usage="usage: %prog [OPTIONS] RemotePort[:LocalPort] [RemotePort[:LocalPort]]...")
parser.add_option("-t", "--threaded", dest='threaded', action='store_true', default=False, help="use threading to handle multiple connections at once")
parser.add_option("-b", "--bufsize", dest='bufsize', action='store', metavar='KILOBYTES', type='int', default=128, help="specify buffer size for socket forwarding")
parser.add_option("-s", "--socket", dest='sockpath', action='store', metavar='PATH', type='str', default=None, help="specify the path of the usbmuxd socket")

options, args = parser.parse_args()

serverclass = TCPServer
if options.threaded:
    serverclass = ThreadedTCPServer

if len(args) == 0:
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)

ports = []

for arg in args:
    try:

#       if ':' in arg:
#           rport, lport = arg.split(":")
#           lport = int(lport)
#           ports.append((rport, lport))
#       else:
#           ports.append((int(arg), int(arg)))

        rport, lport, serial = arg.split(":")
        lport = int(lport)
        ports.append((int(rport), int(lport), serial))

    except:
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit(1)

servers=[]

for rport, lport, serial in ports:
    print "Forwarding local port %d to remote port %d"%(lport, rport)
    server = serverclass((HOST, lport), TCPRelay)
    server.rport = rport
    server.bufsize = options.bufsize
    server.serial = serial
    servers.append(server)

alive = True

while alive:
    try:
        rl, wl, xl = select.select(servers, [], [])
        for server in rl:
            server.handle_request()
    except:
        alive = False
```

Comment: is there any solution for node. We are facing the same issue with node.